# Undefined PHP varible in PHP: variable $_GET_GET. Trying to access array offset on value of type null

Tags: php, mamp, php-8

I've just updated my MAMP to PHP 8 and am trying to migrate my setting to it. In the search bar of my site, it says:

> **Warning**:  Undefined variable $_GET_GET
> on line **968**
> **Warning**:  Trying to access array
> offset on value of type null in

and here's the code that I use:

```
            <input id="search" type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Find articles" value="<?=$_GET_GET['q'];?>"/>
```

It works on the previous version but don't know why it doesn't on PHP8, I guess it's because of the new update but can't find the way to fix it.

Update: I tried $_GET instead of $_GET_GET and it showed 
**Warning**:  Undefined array key. Here's the code of the search bar:

```
<div class="col-md-7">
        <div class="row">
        <input id="search" type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Find articles" value="<?=$_GET['q'];?>"/>
        <button id="searchButton" type="button"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
        <p class="smallHint"><small>Hint: Separate phrases with commas (exploring computer science, high school, 2016)</small></p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Tried `$_GET`? :D

Comment: Just to clarify: it *works* on both (and by that I mean the script executes). The only difference is that before PHP 8, it was a notice and in 8 it's a warning. You probably have your error reporting configured not to show notices.

Comment: @SirPilan This is the code from someone else and I just took charge to upgrade it. I wondered why they use $_GET_GET but it worked on PHP 7, I tried $_GET too and it says "Undefined array key", really don't know what's going on.

Comment: @El_Vanja maybe that's the reason why it shows the error. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[$_GET](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_superglobals_get.asp) is a variable that contains the GET parameters sent to the server. `$_GET_GET` does not exist according to the error, so your fix could be:

```
<input id="search" type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Find articles" value="<?=(isset($_GET['q']) ? $_GET['q'] : 'somedefault');?>"/>
```

If you have actually meant to use `$_GET_GET`, then for some reason it's not initialized properly.

EDIT:

It was pointed out in the comment section that in PHP 7 this issue raised a Notice and in PHP 8 it raises a Warning.

Comment: This is the code from someone else and I just took charge to upgrade it. I wondered why they use $_GET_GET but it worked on PHP 7, I tried $_GET too and it says "Undefined array key", really don't know what's going on.

Comment: `$_GET['q']?:'default'` or `$_GET['q']??'default'` for the cool kids :P - the `??` doesnt throw a notice(v7)/warning(v8) when the key is not present.

Comment: @NicholasThai the problem is surely not caused by the upgrade to PHP 8. It is possible that the code was unchanged and this bug was present in your PHP 7, without ever manifesting. There might be some logic which prevented this from running under PHP 7. So, your problem is in the line you have correctly identified. It is probably a typo, which just didn't manifest before for some reason. However, I guarantee you that if you create an empty page, with just echo var_dump($_GET_GET); and run that under PHP 7, it won't work.

Comment: @LajosArpad Sure, like El_vanja mentioned above, maybe it changed from notice (PHP7) to warning (PHP8), your comment resolved my case. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The variable is $_GET not $_GET_GET